# Не работает reCaptchav2 в fancybox+cf7

Tags: wordpress, fancybox, recaptcha, contact-form7

Добрый день.
Суть проблемы: не работает каптча в модальном окне (фэнсибокс)
Пробовал такой скрипт в шапке, в функциях относительно формы фенсибокса и т.д.

```
var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
      'sitekey' : 'your_site_key'
    });
  };
```

Пробовал поместить такой код к фенсибоксу

```
ajax: {
     complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
            sitekey: [RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY],
            callback: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }           
        });
    }
  }
```

И еще несколько вариантов с помещением скриптов в шапку, тело формы - в результате просто пустой div для капчи.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: что пишется в консоли? ошибок нет?

Comment: раньше не писало ничего, сейчас пишет "reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id". уже хоть что-то
подключал в шапку:
 var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
      'sitekey' : 'your_site_key'
    });
  };
Перед закрывающим боди:
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена следующим:

1. Создаем в форме обертку, например:

```html
<div class="captcha_wrapper"></div>
```

2. Приводим скрипт фенсибокса к такому виду:

```js
$.fancybox({
   $.getScript("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js");
   onComplete: function(){
     $(".captcha_wrapper").append("<div class='g-recaptcha' id='recaptcha' data-sitekey='your_key'></div>");
        var widgetId = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha');
      },
    onCleanup: function(){
      $('#recaptcha').remove();
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

grecaptcha.reset() не помогло, поэтому принудительно удаляем элемент при закрытии модального окна и снова создаем при открытии